# Toggle font-awesome icon on click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to toggle font awesome icons on click. When the page is loaded i query the backend and find out whether a user is enrolled into a course or not, incase they are enrolled I show a tick icon, otherwise I show a coffee icon.

The end goal is have each individual icon change into the opposite when clicked. Currently when i click the icons, for example if i click a cup icon it not only changes into a tick but changes the rest of the cup icons into ticks too. How can I resolve this issue so that when clicked, only the clicked icon is affected?

Here is my code

Functional component

```
export const CourseCard = ({
  video,
  normaluser,
  adminuser,
  userauthenticated,
  adminauthenticated,
  handleUnroll,
  handleEnroll,
  enrolled,
  unrolled
}) => (
    <Grid item xs={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            {(video.enrolled_students.includes(normaluser) &&
              userauthenticated) ||
            (video.enrolled_students.includes(adminuser) &&
              adminauthenticated) ? (
                <div className="enrol__button">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" onClick={() => handleUnroll(video.slug)}>

                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={enrolled ? faCheckSquare : faCoffee}
                      />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            ) : (!video.enrolled_students.includes(normaluser) &&
                userauthenticated) ||
              (!video.enrolled_students.includes(adminuser) &&
                adminauthenticated) ? (
                  <div>
                    <a href="#" onClick={() => handleEnroll(video.slug)}>

                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={unrolled ? faCoffee : faCheckSquare}
                      />
                    </a>
                  </div>
            ) : (
                   ""
            )}
    </Grid>
```

Container

```
export class AllCourses extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.user = details(AUTHENTICATED);
    this.admin = AdminDetails(AUTHENTICATED);

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let normaldetail = details(token);
    this.normaluser = normaldetail.user_id;

    let admindetail = AdminDetails(token);
    this.adminuser = admindetail.user_id;

    this.state = {
      enrolled: true,
      unrolled: true
    };
  }

  handleEnroll = slug => {
    this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));
    this.setState({unrolled: !this.state.unrolled}); 
  }

  handleUnroll = slug => {
    this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));
    this.setState({enrolled: !this.state.enrolled});
  }

  render() {
    const userauthenticated = this.user;
    const adminauthenticated = this.admin;
    const adminuser = this.adminuser;
    const normaluser = this.normaluser;

    const { allCourses } = this.props;
    const {search, enrolled, unrolled} = this.state;

      return (   

                  <div className="container">
                    <Grid
                      container
                      spacing={3}
                      className="courses__row courses__row__medium"
                    >
                      {allCourses.map(video => (
                        <CourseCard
                          key={video.slug}
                          video={video}
                          enrolled={enrolled}
                          unrolled={unrolled}
                          handleEnroll={this.handleEnroll}
                          handleUnroll={this.handleUnroll}
                          normaluser={normaluser}
                          adminuser={adminuser}
                          userauthenticated={userauthenticated}
                          adminauthenticated={adminauthenticated}
                        />
                      ))}
                      ;
                    </Grid>
                  </div>             

      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead a conditional on a boolean try to compare current card key to checked card key

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={this.props.checkedCard == this.props.key ? faCoffee : faCheckSquare} />
```

and in your container :

```
handleEnroll = slug => {
   this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));
   this.setState({checked: this.props.key}); 
}
```

and :

```
<CourseCard
  key={video.slug}
  video={video}
  checkedCard={this.state.checkedCard}
```

Comment: This solution works, the only issue being the state of previous icon is not maintained. So for example if you enroll into one course and then enroll into a the second one, you will notice the previously toggled icon(for first course) going back to its original state. Although when you refresh the page, you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It's because handleEnroll and handleUnroll set state that is shared across all the courses. From what you described it sounds like you want the state to actually be per course.

So you should alter `AllCourses` slightly

```
handleEnroll = slug => {
  // This should cause some change to the relevant course in allCourses
   this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));
}

handleUnroll = slug => {
  // This should cause some change to the relevant course in allCourses
  this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));
}

// Delete this
this.state = {
    enrolled: true,
    unrolled: true
};
```

And then change the CourseCard mapping to use the properties from `video` rather than the ,now eliminated, AllCourses state.

```
{allCourses.map(video => (
 <CourseCard
     key={video.slug}
     video={video}

     enrolled={video.enrolled}
     unrolled={video.unrolled}

     handleEnroll={this.handleEnroll}
     handleUnroll={this.handleUnroll}
     normaluser={normaluser}
     adminuser={adminuser}
     userauthenticated={userauthenticated}
     adminauthenticated={adminauthenticated}
  />
))}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i keep track of the state of icons if i get rid of this.state?

Comment: You either have to move the property so that it is per course, or, rather than having a simple true\false value maintain a list of enrolled and unrolled courses.

The problem is that by having 1 value the state applies to EVERYTHING rather than just 1 specific course

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking in the `Grid` component whether the current user is enrolled or not (by seeing if that `video.enrolled_students` array includes the current user), then those `enrolled` and `unrolled` flags don't seem necessary anymore.

So in `Grid` you should be able to change the first `<FontAwesomeIcon />` call to just:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon='faCheckSquare' />
```

and the second one to

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon='faCoffee' />
```

---

Also, you have a typo in AllCourses where you're calling `this.props.dispatch(Enroll(slug));` in both `handleEnroll` and `handleUnroll` where it should most probably be `Unroll(slug)` in the second one.

Comment: This works, but i have to refresh the page to see a new icon. What i want is for the icon to change without me refreshing the page.